# If $\phi$ is $\mu$-Bochner integrable, is it $\nu$-Bochner integrable for $\nu \ll \mu$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, bochner-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}(\Omega), \mu)$ be a probability space, $B$ be a separable Banach space. Let $\phi : \Omega \to B$ be a bounded (say by $C$) measurable function, which is Bochner integrable for $\mu$.

Let now $\nu \ll \mu$ be a *probability* measure, is $\phi$ Bochner integrable for $\nu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to the new version of the question (assuming $\nu(B)=1$):**  This is true, since any bounded function is integrable with respect to a finite measure. The absolute continuity condition is entirely irrevelant.

**Answer to the old version of the question (no assumption on $\nu(B)$):** No, this isn't even true for the finite-dimensional case. Just take $\Omega=\Bbb R$, $\phi\equiv 1$, $\mu=\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\nu$ to be Lebesgue's measure.

Comment: Well yes, sorry I forgot to mention $\nu$ is also a probability measure.

Comment: Then, it is trivially true, since any bounded function is integrable with respect to a finite measure.

Comment: Well, that's trivial for Lebesgue integration, but I am not sure it holds for Bochner integration.

Comment: It does. $f\colon\Omega\to B$ is $\mu$-Bochner-integrable if and only if $\|f\|\colon\Omega\to [0,\infty)$ is $\mu$-Lebesgue-integrable. If $\mu$ is finite and $f$ is bounded, the latter is given.

Comment: Yes you are right, although we need to state that $f$ is $\mu$-Bochner measurable as a hypothesis I believe, and then surely $f$ is $\nu$-Bochner measurable (by definition).